# nvclock + nvclock_gtk in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: nvidia, overclocking

I know about the Coolbits funktion in the nvidia binary drivers,but if I set coolbits to 12 i only get fan control (the opions only cinda apear).
Since my gpu is a Geforce 8600 Gt i want to use nvclock but i am unable to compile it myself (and there is no ready version for 16.04.3).
my nvidia driver is nvidia binary driver-version 340.102 .